# Different representation of same table in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have question about hibernate. I have class User which contain base information about user.

```
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "surname")
private String surname;

@Column(name = "photo_url")
private String photoURL;
```

Now i need to create class UserFull with extended information about user

```
public class UserFull extends User {

@Column(name = "email")
private String email;

@Column(name = "date_birthday")
private Date dateBirthday;

@Column(name = "date_registration")
private Date dateRegistration;
```

How can i implement such extending with hibernate? Both classes reference on same table "user".

Answer (score 0):

This code will do what you want to achieve

```
 @Entity  
    @Table(name="User")  
    @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) //Least normalisation strategy  
    public class User
    { 
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "id")
        private int id;

        @Column(name = "name")
        private String name;

        @Column(name = "surname")
        private String surname;

        @Column(name = "photo_url")
        private String photoURL;
    }

    @Entity  
    @Table(name="UserFull")  
    public class UserFull extends User {

        @Column(name = "email")
        private String email;

        @Column(name = "date_birthday")
        private Date dateBirthday;

        @Column(name = "date_registration")
        private Date dateRegistration;
   }
```